# Mesos task - Failed to accept socket: future discarded

Tags: docker, mesos, mesos-chronos

I am just trying to upgrade mesos version to 1.3.1 from 1.0.3.

Chronos scheduler is able to schedule the JOB thru mesos. The job runs fine and able to see mesos stdout logs. But, still seeing the following in mesos stderr logs.  The docker jobs runs fine, but still the status is showing as failed with the below logs.

```
I0905 22:05:00.824811   456 exec.cpp:162] Version: 1.3.1
I0905 22:05:00.829165   459 exec.cpp:237] Executor registered on agent c63c93dc-3d9f-4322-9f82-0553fd1324fe-S0
E0905 22:05:11.773236   465 process.cpp:956] Failed to accept socket: future discarded
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do not worry. This line was introduced in 1.3 by [r/58557/](https://reviews.apache.org/r/58557/) and will be fixed in 1.4

> This log line is not usually a problem, and reporting it as an error can
>   cause needless debugging. [r/59817](https://reviews.apache.org/r/59817/)