# Mesos Future discarded

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I am trying to run a spark job via Mesos

it throws an exception

> WARN MesosExternalShuffleClient: Unable to register app
>   6c1b7274-960f-47ef-9fa7-1dd06b05d4f1-0010

with external shuffle service.

Please manually remove shuffle data after driver exit

> Error:**java.lang.RuntimeException:
>   java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Unexpected message:
>   org.apache.spark.network.shuffle.protocol.mesos.RegisterDriver@88d86a24
>   "**

and the logs in Stderr as

> ERROR CoarseGrainedExecutorBackend: RECEIVED SIGNAL TERM
>       INFO DiskBlockManager: Shutdown hook called
>       E0911 05:32:34.711486  6619 process.cpp:951] Failed to accept socket: future discarded**

**In Spark-Defaults.conf**

```
spark.mesos.coarse          true
spark.network.timeout           3600s
spark.shuffle.io.connectionTimeout  3600s
```

Who is killing my application..?

Comment: It's probably not a problem with future discarded https://stackoverflow.com/a/46123514/1387612

Comment: I am trying to [set up Mesos cluster](http://mesos.apache.org/gettingstarted/) and when I do `make check` I get 8 test fails, first one being this.

Comment: `./bin/mesos-tests.sh --gtest_filter="CommandExecutorCheckTest.HTTPCheckDelivered" --verbose
`
Test mentioned in gtest_filter fails!

Comment: It looks like this tests are flaky, see [MESOS-7440](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-7440)